# Passing different parameter to function and modifer

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, modifiers, function

I  want to know that is there any way to provide different parametres to function and modifer while declaring them . Below is the code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16 ;
contract logic
{
    uint a ;
    uint g ;
    modifier check(uint  c)
    {
        require( c == 7 , 'wrong');
        _;
    }

    function reolace( uint  b) public  check(  uint h)
    {           
                 a = b ;
    }
}
```

What is want is that I should be able to pass different values to `uint b` and `uint h` & the value passed in `h` should be checked in modifer if it is equal to 7 or not.
However , when I tried to compile I get the following error :-

[image]

However if I pass the same parameter to both function and modifer i.e. if I used

`function reolace( uint  b) public  check(b)`

then programme compiles correctly.Is it necessary to pass ame paramter at both place or is there any way to pass different paramteres of same/different  data types ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple look here,

```
function reolace(uint b, uint h) public check(h)
{           
             a = b ;
}
```

you just need to define in function parameters and pass that variable. I hope you understand